# My application keeps crashing I'm unable to find the problem

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, crash

xml file for sign up activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SignUp"
    android:background="@drawable/splashbackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text=" Sign In "
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:background="#469BABC6"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/headingTV"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/headingTV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headingTV"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:textSize="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_person_24"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textSize="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_lock_24"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editText1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/editText1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:elevation="150dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextback"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/sign"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/sign"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sign"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

main activity.kt file for splash screen activity

```
package com.example.disneyloginpage

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            var intent=Intent(this,SignUp::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        },3000)
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an application that shows a splash screen for 3 seconds and then opens a sign in activity. In the first activity I have used handler postdelayed method for splash screen and in second activity it's just a ui but the application keeps crashing after splash screen. What should I do there is no error in any activity.

Comment: Start by looking into the Logcat - are there any exception stacktraces? A stacktrace will likely point to a line in code that is problematic.

Comment: Agreed, please [look at the Logcat output and examine the stack trace associated with your crash](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html).

Comment: you can try looking logCat and check if there is any problem with the SignUp activity. because the main activity looks fine the problem might be after switching the main activity to the sighup activity.

Comment: Thank you so much  reading and understanding the logcat and stack trace solved my problem. There was a problem in button component. Finally after deleting the selectable attribute, my application runs smoothly without any crashes.